# Adding data to db that comes from DTOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

I have entities and related DTOs which are used to transfer data from DB (Entity framework 6) to different layers of my web api. Here is the code:

```
    public class Dish
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double PreparationTime { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();

        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

        public virtual ICollection<IngredientAmount> IngredientAmounts { get; set; } = new List<IngredientAmount>();

        public virtual ICollection<RecipeUnit> RecipeUnits { get; set; } = new List<RecipeUnit>();
    }
```

```
public class DishDetailedDTO: IDishDTO
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double PreparationTime { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public List<CategoryDTO> Categories { get; set; }

        public List<IngredientDetailedDTO> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public List<IngredientAmountDTO> IngredientAmounts { get; set; }

        public List<RecipeUnitDTO> RecipeUnits { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; } = new List<Dish>();
    }
```

```
    public class CategoryDTO: ICategoryDTO
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem comes in when I try to add new Dish object which navigation property(lets say category) alredy exists in database. Generaly I get DishDTO from somewhere (frontend), then use automapper to map it to Dish and then add this Dish to context. Here is the reproduction of the problem in smaller scale:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x=> 
            {
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishDetailedDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishAvailableIngredientsDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<DishDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<DishDetailedDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<DishAvailableIngredientsDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<CategoryDTO, Category>();
                x.CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDetailedDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientDTO, Ingredient>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientDetailedDTO, Ingredient>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientAmount, IngredientAmountDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientAmountDTO, IngredientAmount>();
                x.CreateMap<RecipeUnit, RecipeUnitDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<RecipeUnitDTO, RecipeUnit>();
            });

            var context = new EFDbContext();

            var dish = new DishDetailedDTO()
            {
                Name = "SomeName",
                Categories = new List<CategoryDTO>
                { 
                   new CategoryDTO()
                   {
                       Name = "Breakfast"
                   }
                }
            };

            context.Dishes.Add(Mapper.Map<Dish>(dish));
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Then I've got exception

```
SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Categories' with unique index 'IX_Name'. The duplicate key value is (Breakfast).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: A dish can have multiple categories? so basically you have 1 to many relation between dish and categories?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Yes

Comment: you can't add the mapped dish with all categories directly to the dbset. Either exclude the navigation property from the mapped to be added dish and add/exclude the related category, or set the entity state of the related categories to their actual state.

Answer (score 0):

the design of your `Dish` model is wrong, one `Dish` can have multiple `Categories` and one `Category` can have multiple `Dishes` which makes it a many to many relation. To handle this situation you need to add another model something like:-

```
public class DishCategoryMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
}
```

then your dish model will look like

```
public class Dish
{
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DishCategoryMapping> DishCategoryMappings { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

then you will insert a row for each category that a dish has in the `DishCategoryMapping` table.

Comment: That's true for domain model classes. The relation there is many to many. But it my DTOs there is no need to pass list of related dishes in the category class

Comment: look at the exception, `cannot insert duplicate in dbo.Categories` why do you think EF is trying to insert into the Categories table when you are inserting a new Dish? Its because when you are creating a DishDTO you are also initializing the List<CategoryDTO>. Then when your automapper tries to map your DishDTO into Dish it also initializes the virtual Category List property in Dish which is why EF is trying to insert into the categories table as well